# gazebo_ros problem after installing drcsim

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I had Gazebo 1.9 working well with ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 (gazebo on its own, ros on its own, and gazebo with ros integration all worked fine). Then I installed DRCSim without thinking too carefully about it and I think that upgraded Gazebo to 3.0 (now I have a /usr/share/gazebo-3.0 with the worlds having been moved there and gazebo rotation button has a different effect).

Now Gazebo on its own and ROS on its own still work, but when I try using roslaunch for a gazebo_ros package, gazebo will start but the models won't get spawned. I changed my gazebo resource path to 3.0 (I have this in my .bashrc: export GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH=/usr/share/gazebo-3.0:/usr/share/gazebo_models:~/catkin_ws/src) but that didn't fix it. Are there other aspects that I can change that would fix this, or is the issue that I now have Gazebo 3.0 with Hydro? And if it's the latter, is there some way to uninstall/install to get it to work again?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6767/gazebo_ros-problem-after-installing-drcsim/) by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-08-10**:
Am I asking a stupid question, or is there just no answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

So I have no idea why but I just waited a few days and now everything related to the gazebo_ros package works fine.

---

Originally posted by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) with karma: 104 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nbanyk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/857/nbanyk/) on 2014-08-12**:
and I don't have enough points to accept my own answer so I can't close out the question